# mpd: Failed to read mixer for 'My ALSA Device': no such mixer control: PCM

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa, music, mpd

I had mpd/mpc running on my Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS headless, X-less server.  I decided to switch out the songs; I moved the old songs out of the /Music directory, moved the new songs in, and ran `mpc update`, but it failed to resume playing.

Naturally, I started changing things, according to what I could find on Google, but nothing seems to work.

When I run mpc commands, like `mpc status`, I get the error message `Failed to read mixer for 'My ALSA Device': no such mixer control: PCM`.

I can play music when I use the command `sudo aplay piano.wav`, and similar commands.

Here's some diagnostic info: http://pastebin.com/1CzbeYBC.  It contains

- /etc/mpd.conf
- aplay -L
- aplay -l
- mpd verbose from the command line
- amixer & amixer contents

I would appreciate any pointers!  Thank you.

Comment: Why `sudo`? Don't you have access to the device nodes in `/dev/snd/`? Are you member of the `audio` group?

Comment: @CL: mpd runs under the account mpd, but that account doesn't have login privileges, so I use sudo when debugging.  My login is not a member of the audio group, but mpd is.  /dev/snd/* have crw-rw---T permissions, and belong to the group audio.

Comment: I added alsa-info.sh output:  http://pastebin.com/2zmWPKv6

Comment: Does `amixer set "PCM" 0dB` work? If yes, something has changed with the mpd configuration.

Comment: @CL: `amixer set "PCM" 0dB` gives me the following output:  `Simple mixer control 'PCM',0  
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum  
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right  
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31  
  Mono:  
  Front Left: Playback 23 [74%] [0.00dB] [on]  
  Front Right: Playback 23 [74%] [0.00dB] [on]`    which is a change from `Playback 28 [90%] [7.50dB]`

Comment: @CL: Continued... I don't know if that's what you meant when you asked if it "worked".  Yet aplay still works and mpd still does not.

Comment: Yes, that works. If `amixer` and `aplay` work, then there is nothing wrong with your ALSA configuration. It is possible that mpd does not have rights you think it has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@CL was right; alsa was working but mpd was not.

I discovered that if I switched to the home folder of the mpd user (`export HOME=/var/log/mpd`), the aplay commands (e.g. `sudo -u mpd aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`) would no longer work.

More Googling until I found http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1138454

The solution was `sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio`.  Once that was done, everything was working again.

Answer (score 1):

Since your using MPD with pulseaudio, you can change the audio_output accordingly:

```
sudo nano /etc/mpd.conf
```

Comment this section:

```
#audio_output {
#   type       "alsa"
#   name       "My ALSA Device"
#   device      "hw:0,0"    # optional
#   mixer_type      "hardware"      # optional
#   mixer_device    "default"   # optional
#   mixer_control   "PCM"       # optional
#   mixer_index "0"     # optional
#}
```

Uncomment this

```
audio_output {
    type        "pulse"
    name        "My Pulse Output"
#   server      "remote_server"     # optional
#   sink        "remote_server_sink"    # optional
}
```

You may have to add rights on the mpd user too:

```
sudo adduser mpd pulse
sudo adduser mpd pulse-access
```

Restart your MPD:

```
sudo systemctl restart mpd
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to set mixer_control to "Headphones" as `amixer` output suggested.

```
audio_output {
   type          "alsa"
   name          "My ALSA Device"
   mixer_control "Headphones"
}
```

This is for the Raspberry Pi 1 B.

Comment: On my Raspberry Pi 1 B+ the correct mixer is `"Headphone"` without "s" at the end. You can check this with `amixer scontrols`.